# Windows Phone VB "NavigationService is not declared"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

Im creating a very simple Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio Express. I have added a Hyperlink control, then from that I have double click to go to the relevant VB page.

As instructed by the many tutorials out there I have added the code for the button - which should navigate it to the second page I have created.

```
Private Sub hyperlinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
End Sub
```

However VB keeps on giving me the error "NavigationService is not declared"

Searching the error message has given me very little joy so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, code for navigation to another page are declared as,

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just call the class as you will need to get it from the app (so that the system navigates within the app). This is done by accessing the `PhoneApplicationFrame`!

It should look something like this:

```
Private Sub hyperlinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Uri uri = New Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(uri)
End Sub
```